# DateTime operator giving strange results

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have two SQL query strings, one of which works and one of which doesn't.

The working one:

```
string updateLoginTime = "UPDATE DeviceUsers SET lastLogin = '" + dateTime + "' WHERE ID = '" + userID + "'";
```

This one doesn't:

```
string updateText = "UPDATE DocumentsRead SET timeRead = '" + dateTime + "' WHERE userID = '" + userID + "' AND fileName = '" + fileOnly +"'";
```

It throws an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

In both queries the `dateTime` parameter is passed into a web method as a string.
Any ideas why the first one works but the second doesn't?

-EDIT-

The second query is now formatted as follows:

```
dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH-mm-ss");

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EndUsersConnectionString"].ConnectionString)) 
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();

    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE DocumentsRead SET timeRead = @timeRead WHERE userID = @userID AND fileName = @fileName";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeRead", dateTime);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fileName);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Still getting the same error.

Comment: That's so [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)...

Comment: What is the (string) value of `dateTime` at that point?

Comment: What is the type of `userID` and `fileName` columns? What is `userID` and `fileOnly` variables? Looks like you try to cast big `varchar` value to `datetime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your datatypes on the table properties.

DeviceUsers.lastLogin type seems to be correctly set to Date, but perhaps DocumentsRead.timeRead isn't correctly configured.

Comment: Turns out it was actually the other way around - `DeviceUsers.lastLogin` type was `nvarchar`. I've managed to crowbar some functionality out of it by setting `DocumentsRead.timeRead` to `nvarchar` too.

Answer (score 10):

Never do that. **NEVER** use string concatenations to build SQL queries. **ALWAYS** use parametrized queries if you don't want to meet [`Bobby Tables`](http://xkcd.com/327/):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(someConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE DocumentsRead SET timeRead = @timeRead WHERE userID = @userID AND fileName = @fileName";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeRead", someDateTimeInstance);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fileName);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This way not only that you won't meet with Bobby Tables but your query will work correctly.

The golden rule that should be respected when doing SQL development is not never use the `+` operator.

Comment: 3 mentions of Bobby but not one of SQL injection so far. Added for Google.

Comment: I've re-formatted the way you've shown but am still seeing the same error. I'll edit the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenating sql query is a bad practice in common so it is better to use parametrized query, however in your case you're possibly working in an environment with different locales so the application server and dbms use different date formats (dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy for example)